# Android X : Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton - android

Tags: java, android

I have this error
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
I want my project to be compatible with androidx
My project was not compatible with androidx I used API28

```
// _______________ xml ____________________________

<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:borderWidth="0dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add"
        android:visibility="invisible"/>
//____________________________________________________

//______________  gradle app _______________________
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'

    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.2'

    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
//___________________________________________________

//______________  gradle propieties ____________________

android.useAndroidX=true

android.enableJetifier=true

//_____________________________________________________
```

Comment: The inflation exception says you are using a support FAB.

Comment: The floatinactionbutton is called fab

Comment: I left the actionbutonfloating in support in another file